# Is it good/allowed to link SO questions to this website

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed/good practice to add a comment to Magento related SO questions like this?

> please mind posting your question at https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless Magento was somehow deemed off topic at Stack Overflow, **you should *not* solicit content like that.** Consider that Stack Overflow users may not *want* to have their content lured away like that. In addition, the noise and harassment factor of every question being met with *"psst, hey... over here"* is a bit user hostile.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think a friendly comment stating that the question would be welcome on the Magento site would be good. A lot of people don't even know this site exists so automatically post on SO. A friendly comment would bolster this community and make it more and more useful for Magento Devs.

How often have we seen "MySQL functions are deprecated" in comments for PHP questions? It's nothing to do with the post, it's not been asked by the user however, it's useful advice and if we can't give that, what's the point in a community driven site?

Perhaps the wording could be changed though, something like "Have you considered posting your question on Magento.stackexchange.com?" as it's more inviting that instructive.